# kornShell and AIX unable to create an Array Variable

Tags: aix, array

```
LS=`ls "$SRC_PATH"/* | grep -i -v *.ignore`
```

I cannot use for loop as I need to check conditions with while as there are multiple conditions.

Trying to access the content using

```
${LS[$CNT]}
CNT=`expr $CNT + 1`
```

I am unable to access the contents.

Answer (score 2):

We'll start with [Do not parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) because it's always good to remind people of this.

Next note that the `grep` probably isn't doing what you want; you likely want `\.ignore$` to make it skip files ending with ".ignore"

Since we're using `ksh` you don't need to call `expr`; you can just do `let CNT=CNT+1`

Now..

To set an array in `ksh` you need to use `set -A` syntax.

eg

```
set -A LS $(ls "$SRC_PATH"/* | grep -i -v '\.ignore$')
```

Now `${LS[0]}` will be the first file, etc etc.

eg if we have

```
$ ls X               
a  b  c
```

Then

```
$ set -A LS $(ls X)
$ echo ${LS[0]}
a
$ echo ${LS[1]}
b
$ echo ${LS[2]}
c
```